# How do you join elasticsearch indexes to sort?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a preferred way to join two Elasticsearch indices so that I can sort my query?

Index #1

```
// GET /activities/_doc/1aadea40-e93b-42b4-9c76-05ebed4335fe (simplified output)
{
  "_index" : "activities-1605040906149",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "1aadea40-e93b-42b4-9c76-05ebed4335fe",
  "_source" : {
    "date" : 1614286078420,
    "activityId" : "1aadea40-e93b-42b4-9c76-05ebed4335fe",
    "referralId" : "943f6d94-b2dd-4e89-9383-447fdd1d73d8",
    "duration" : 90
  }
}
```

Index #2

```
// GET /referrals/_doc/2c022a6e-2543-4cdd-8595-98aea41e8966 (simplified output)
{
  "_index" : "referrals-1612984843755",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "2c022a6e-2543-4cdd-8595-98aea41e8966",
  "_source" : {
    "displayName" : "JOHN DOE",
    "referralId" : "2c022a6e-2543-4cdd-8595-98aea41e8966",
  }
}
```

I’d like to be able to join the contents of the `referrals` index with the contents of my `activities` index and then sort based on the referral’s `displayName`. I would need to do this for tens of thousands of records.

Other solutions include denormalizing my data, but I was hoping to see if there was an alternative way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do joins by following ways

- nested structure : map using an object ,no need of joins
- parent-child relationship : use a 'type' field to distinguish you documents using different type for a same index ,indexing parent and child into the same shard,hence query will be limited to single shard
- application side joins : For example,add activities fields directly in the referrals documents, allowing you to search/query on them directly.

then you can sort based on the referral’s field

Comment: Thank you. I believe I will have to normalize my data by using a nested structure.